# Possible increase in support requests for Stack Overflow for Teams on MSO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams, announcement

Starting today you may see increased activity of Stack Overflow for Teams support questions here on MSO. We're offering the Basic tier of Stack Overflow for Teams free for unlimited users through the end of June 2020 - and those new users will be pointed to MSO as a place to ask questions. We hope to help companies stay connected and easily share knowledge while they are working from home to help reduce the spread of COVID-19.

We’re not sure how much more activity we’ll see but to help make sure these new Teams have the guidance they need, our Teams staff are doing a few things:

- New users will have access to a [landing page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/collaboration) with helpful information.
- We’ll be hosting weekly webinars for Teams Q&A.
- We’re inviting new Teams users to ask any questions here on MSO that aren’t answered on the landing page, in the [Teams Help Center](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/home) and in the Webinars and having Teams and Support staff answering those questions.
- We’re also planning on creating a Teams FAQ here, similar to the one we have [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), so that Teams users can easily find the answers to the questions they have.

You may interact with these posts normally - we just wanted to give you a heads-up of what may be coming around. We don’t expect this to flood MSO or to drive crazy levels of activity, but it might be noticeable. If you see questions that are only reasonably answerable by staff, please nominate them for escalation by flagging them, as per [the escalation process we are currently testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345032/community-and-moderator-guidelines-for-escalating-issues-via-new-response-proces). As always, feel free to reach out and answer here if you have any questions, we’ll be around to clarify things.

Comment: Except from escalation I assume I can handle these posts as any other post, that is what you mean with "normally" right? Like editing, voting and closing as duplicates, among other moderation options?

Comment: @rene Yep! But also - if you (or anyone) happens to know the answer because you use Teams, feel free to help out with an answer, too! :) We're going to be supporting these questions but y'all don't have to avoid answering because of that. :)

Comment: @Catija awesome! I spot an opportunity to work on my Meta rep ... ;)

Comment: I might be missing something but why is MSO used as first line support for Teams?

Comment: @ivarni I don’t know that I’d call it a first line. The question outlines several other ways of getting information about how to use Teams. MSO is an *additional* resource in the same way it is for Jobs and Talent. Also, as I think we’d all agree, our platform is great for answering a question once for the benefit of many. Direct requests to our support Team would need to be answered many times. It’d be great to have a sub-meta of some sort for our other products but until we can figure that out, MSO is still really useful.