# Does getting answers to fairly complex questions become harder on Stack Overflow / Meta?

Tags: discussion, answers

I am a fairly old member on Stack (mainly answering), but every now and then I am asking a question. I have noticed that for most of my latest questions I had to rely on bounties to get an answer (or even a useful comment).

Also, on Meta I have noticed that it is harder to get an answer than it used to be (my first questions received an answer in several hours, now I had contact support because I had no reaction in two days).

For the main site, it's not a big issue because I can afford to offer bounties, but for the second it's a little more tricky. As I am trying to use Stack Overflow for Teams where I work (I am promoting it), one of the "selling" points I am using is the quick support of the community on Meta. This is pretty disappointing especially when I see time and money wasted on [side topics like this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction).

I tried to check if there is indeed a problem with getting your questions answered on Stack ([these queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1258922) started from [this query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61303/311064)):

- getting an accepted answer seems to take on average more than it used to be. This might also be caused by users simply forgetting to accept an answer.
- getting the first answer with a score > 0 seems to take less than it used to be.

One aspect I am unable to grasp with my queries is the question complexity. I typically ask a question after at least trying a couple of solutions and most of them are beyond trivial ones.

I am looking for community feedback related to my issue: getting answers to fairly complex questions seems to be harder than it used to be).

Comment: A lot of the good questions get buried under piles on piles of outright garbage on main, at least depending on the tags. I can't speak for questions on meta that require staff answers though, but they've intentionally avoided meta in the past.,

Comment: @Zoe "they've intentionally avoided meta in the past." does not sound OK, since some of the questions are targeting Stack Overflow for Teams which is a source of revenue for the company.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394736/possible-increase-in-support-requests-for-stack-overflow-for-teams-on-mso) regarding Stack Overflow for Teams.

Comment: There's actually very few teams questions on Meta compared to the "thousands of organizations around the globe" (according to Stack Overflow) who use Teams. I kinda assumed email or whatever was the preferred support medium for teams

Comment: Why should I answer a complex question and maybe get a single upvote and possibly acceptance when I can answer the 8423rd duplicate of how to replace a string within a substring, get double-digit upvotes?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Maybe because you are so bored of answering duplicates again and again (and for all foreseeable times) that this way of teaching is just not worth your time, whatever the number of upvotes or thanks you may get for it? Unfortunately you might overlook the few pearls, which do exists here and there. In a way they might be collateral damage, covered by a huge pile of low quality contributions, effectively rendered invisible.

Comment: @Trilarion I apologize, I forgot to put the `</sarcasm>` tag on that one :). Since answering duplicates is rewarded, asking duplicates is rewarded, so finding the pearls among all those duplicates is that much harder. I agree they are collateral damage, and avoidable, if duplicates were easier to identify (before the asking) and remove (after the asking).