# Teams for free so why is our renewal 120$?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Why is the payment history page looking to charge us 120$ again on the renew date?

We should be merged into the free plan as it's free for up to 50 users and we are only using it for 3 users.

[image: The page lists the current plan as basic and the number of users at 3.]

Can someone from the staff assist us?

Comment: The *Basic* and *Free* plans are _not_ the same (even excluding the user limit), for example the basic plan has SSO support, why would you automatically be merged into the free plan at risk of breaking that or removing the full archive search functionality you may be using? I'd expect this to be something you have to _request_.

Comment: Because we dont use any of those options?

Comment: Is this related to them [offering the Basic tier for free until June 2020](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394736/possible-increase-in-support-requests-for-stack-overflow-for-teams-on-mso)?

Answer (score 18):

You can downgrade your Team to Free if you have 50 or fewer team members. This can be done within the Plans tab of Admin Settings. Please reach out to teams-support@stackoverflow.com if you run into any issues downgrading.

We'll also be sending communications in the coming days to Teams with less than 50 users who aren't paying anything today letting them know they can downgrade. Legally, we can't downgrade a Team without permissions.

Please let me know if there are other questions on this topic!

Comment: "Legally, we can't downgrade...." - What law would this violate?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I'm guessing it would violate the terms of the original contract.

Comment: Each tier of Stack Overflow for Teams has its own set of legal terms that you agree to when you create a Team. When you downgrade your Team, you'll be accepting those specific terms.

Comment: @RobertColumbia The Free plan lacks some integration with other services, so automatically downgrading all those users may break things for Teams who make use of such features.