# Will "Free 10" promotion Teams be charged for SSO?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Several years ago I signed up for a Team when [the pricing page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389175/is-teams-a-free-product-for-teams-with-fewer-than-11-members) said the first 10 members are free. I never got to 11 members. Today I got an email saying there would be a change to my billing because it will now cost an extra $1 per member for SSO. That's sorta strange since I'm not using SSO. But I figured I'd take a look at the site and see if I could avoid that cost. I got this pop-up:

[image: Price increase or no?]

Now I haven't been paying $5/user/month. And the bold sentence implies that I was using the "Free 10" promotion and that will be respected. So I *think* I'll be charged $1/user/month if I don't do anything. Or is it $6/user/month as the "Current Plan" box says?

Making the situation just a little less clear, the billing page (`/admin/billing/plan`) says I'm using the Basic plan that includes SSO. Further on it shows other plans:

[image: Downgrade to Free]

As far as I can tell, the only difference is SSO, which I don't need. In fact, my understanding at the time was the next tier up included SSO. It seems I've been moved up a tier somehow. So I believe it's best to downgrade to Free to avoid paying for a feature I don't want.

But that gets me back to the sentence about the "Free 10" promotion. What does it mean that it will "continue to be respected". And how much will be be charged if people who signed up under that plan do nothing?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406061/teams-for-free-so-why-is-our-renewal-120 - You can't be automatically downgraded to the free tier because it requires you accepting a different set of terms. (I read this as being charged $1/usr/mo, not totally clear though)

Comment: @Nick: That sounds about right. Of course from my point of view I was automatically upgraded to a service I don't need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The free slots will remain free, regardless of the price per seat. So if you wish to keep your 10-free team, you may do so *and* have SSO and whatever other features we come out with in the future that get added to Basic. If you'd rather have more slots than the SSO or other Basic features, I'd recommend you downgrade to Free and then you don't have to be concerned about having too many people on the Team.

The addition of SSO to all paid tiers was a feature that we thought was important to have  so, while it may feel like you got upgraded a tier, it's definitely intended to be the other way around - where we've expanded our offerings to a lower tier rather than keeping it for the higher-level tiers.

I'm in a similar situation - I have a 10-free team with exactly one member and now that there's an option to get up to 50 free, I'm thinking about downgrading and actually using the Team - for what... who knows... Q&A about Catija? Would that be interesting to 49 people? Probably not so much.

Anyway, don't worry about losing those 10 free slots or them starting to cost $1 each now. They're still free! That's what we're respecting - that you had 10 free seats.

Comment: Nice. I'd totally join a Q&A about Catija. ;-)

Comment: I'll send you an invite. :P