# How does SO Teams pricing behave when you add a 51st member?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am thinking about using SO Teams in my organization, but I find one thing not clear in pricing. For up to 50 people Teams is free, but what happens when I add the 51st member? Will I get billed only for this 1 additional person or from that point for all 51 people?

Comment: The way I understand it is that "Free" and "Basic" are two separate plans with different sets of features. So, if your organization has more than 50 people, you'll have to upgrade to a higher plan (e.g., Basic). Otherwise, you'd have 50 people using the features available in the free plan and one person who gets to use the additional features? It doesn't make much sense. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Not to mention that each plan ["has its own set of legal terms that you agree to when you create a Team"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406061/teams-for-free-so-why-is-our-renewal-120#comment831781_406062).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I *speculated* in the comments, Free and Basic are two separate plans with different sets of features. So, if your organization has more than 50 people, you'll have to upgrade to a higher plan (e.g., Basic). Otherwise, you'd have 50 people using the features available in the free plan and one person who gets to use the additional features? It doesn't make much sense.

This is **confirmed** by a [staff member](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija) in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362203/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-free-for-up-to-50-users-forever#comment1211383_362996) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> The features associated with Basic are different than with the Free tier, so if you need to upgrade to Basic to allow space for additional members, you'd be paying the per-seat cost for all 51 seats. We don't give 50 free seats in the Basic or Business tiers.

Also, not to mention the different legal terms issue mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406061/teams-for-free-so-why-is-our-renewal-120#comment831781_406062):

> Each tier of Stack Overflow for Teams has its own set of legal terms that you agree to when you create a Team. When you downgrade your Team, you'll be accepting those specific terms.